# Difference between -x and ~x+1

Tags: performance, assembly, compilation

I do know that for signed 32-bit or 64-bit integers `-x` and `~x + 1` returns the same result.

But I have a few questions :

1. Does the compiler translate them as the same operation ?
2. Why ?
3. If it doesn't, how are they translated ?
4. If it doesn't, then does `-x` have a direct hardware implementation ?

Comment: Look at compiler output yourself on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, for x86, MIPS, ARM, PowerPC, and even AVR (8-bit RISC microcontroller).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, it's a great link to see what happens ! I can see that they're translated to the same output excepted on x86-64 clang.

Comment: Huh?  Did you forget to enable optimization or something?  [They compile the same for me, with clang3.7.1](https://godbolt.org/g/SUh9T3), to `neg     edi` / `mov     eax, edi` / `ret`.  Nobody cares (much) about non-optimized compiler output.

Comment: @PeterCordes right i forgot, they compile the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the compiler translate them as the same operation?

That depends on how smart your compiler is and whether you have turned on optimizations or not. Generally, you can expect a good compiler to generate the same code for both.

> Why?

Some optimizers have a rule to optimize `~x + 1` to `-x`, some don't. This kind of optimization is typically part of a [peephole optimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization), you might want to read the linked article for details.

> If it doesn't, how are they translated ?

That depends on the target platform. For example, on i386, with `x` in the `eax` register, `-x` might be translated to

```
neg %eax
```

whereas `~x + 1` might be translated to

```
not %eax
inc %eax
```

On other platforms, the translation is different. For example, on ARM, the first is

```
rsb r0,r0,#0
```

and the second is

```
mvn r0,r0
add r0,r0,#1
```

> If it doesn't, then does -x have a direct hardware implementation ?

Typically there is either an instruction for negation or the compiler simply subtracts the value from zero as 0 − *x* = −*x* by definition.